# Address in C: &(number)

Tags: c

I don't understand the output of this program:

```
int arr[]={1,7,4,2,5,8};
int x=(&(arr[arr[1]-arr[4]])-arr);
printf("%d" ,x);
```

`arr[arr[1]-arr[4]]` is equal to 4. What does it mean `&(4)`?  Why does it print 2?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
arr[1] - arr[4]
```

This is just as it looks. `7 - 5 = 2`, so let's replace that with `2`:

```
arr[2]
```

That's also just as it looks. `4`. The `&` takes its address, which will be two `int`s offset from the beginning of the array, which is `arr`.

```
&(arr[2]) - arr
```

That subtracts `arr`, so you're left with the offset of `arr[2]` from `arr`, which is two `int`s. There you go.

[Here's a reduced example.](http://codepad.org/OgM4mIiK)

---

In case you were expecting it to be `8`, well, that's just how pointer arithmetic is. Casting them both to `unsigned int`:

```
(unsigned int)&arr[2] - (unsigned int)arr
```

will yield `8`, at least when an `int` is four bytes. [(Demo)](http://codepad.org/XQGzvR9f)

Answer (score 5):

Look at minitech's answer for showing how the print value of "2" can be deduced.

However, I think that in your case you just misunderstood how the `&` operator works. Yes, `arr[arr[1]-arr[4]]` is `4`, but that does not mean that `&(arr[arr[1]-arr[4]])` is doing `&4`; it's doing `&(arr[2])`; and it's taking the address of `arr[2]`, not the value of `arr[2]`, which is `4`.